# YAML Pipeline Setting Pipeline Variables in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

The following is a piece of YAML code from my pipeline. I am trying to write a power shell script for setting versions. Basically, I have some Web UI variables and I want the power shell script to check if these were changed. If they were, I want MAJOR_VERSION and MINOR_VERSION to be updated and the value of MAJOR_REVISION to be reset. I want these changes to persist through future pipeline runs.

Currently, the output is...

```
GL_MAJOR_VERSION: 4 
GL_MINOR_VERSION: 1
MAJOR_VERSION: 
MINOR_VERSION: 
Update to version number detected.
MAJOR_VERSION Post Change: 
MINOR_VERSION Post Change:
```

```
#### SETUP 
resources:
  - repo: self
    clean: true

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

#### VARIABLES
variables:
  BuildPlatform: "x64"
  BuildConfiguration: "Debug"
  solution: '**\*Mysolution.sln'
  MAJOR_VERSION: 
  MINOR_VERSION: 
  MAJOR_REVISION: $[counter(format('{0}', variables['MAJOR_REVISION']),'0')]
  RELEASE_ID: '0.0.0'

# triggered - Ignore for now. 
trigger: none

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Preparing Version Number'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        
          Write-Host "GL_MAJOR_VERSION: ${env:GL_MAJOR_VERSION}"
          Write-Host "GL_MINOR_VERSION: ${env:GL_MINOR_VERSION}"
          Write-Host "MAJOR_VERSION: $(MAJOR_VERSION)"
          Write-Host "MINOR_VERSION: $(MINOR_VERSION)"
          # Check major and minor version. 
          if((${env:GL_MAJOR_VERSION} -ne "$(MAJOR_VERSION)" -or ${env:GL_MINOR_VERSION} -ne "$(MINOR_VERSION)")) {
            Write-Host "Update to version number detected."
            Set-Variable -Name 'MAJOR_VERSION' -Value ${env:GL_MAJOR_VERSION}
            Set-Variable -Name 'MINOR_VERSION' -Value ${env:GL_MINOR_VERSION}
            #Trying something different
            ##vso[task.setvariable variable=MAJOR_VERSION;]${env:GL_MAJOR_VERSION}
            #Trying something different - ignored as it throws error
            #MAJOR_REVISION = 0
          }
          Write-Host "MAJOR_VERSION Post Change: $(MAJOR_VERSION)"
          Write-Host "MINOR_VERSION Post Change: $(MINOR_VERSION)"
          # Get the major version and minor version from environment variables
          $version_major = $(MAJOR_VERSION)
          $version_minor = $(MINOR_VERSION)
```